# RegExp: Extract number that's wrapped in

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So here's my issue. I need to extract the 12345 from any of the following:

```
var dURL1='http://www.domain.com/?some_id=12345';
var dURL2='http://www.domain.com/sub/anotherSub/12345';
var dURL3='http://www.domain.com/sub/anotherSub/12345-some-random-text';
var dURL4='sub/anotherSub/12345';
var dURL5='sub/anotherSub/12345-some-other-random-text';
var dURL6='/sub/anotherSub/12345';
var dURL7='/sub/anotherSub/12345-some-other-random-text';
```

I have:

```
/(\S+)?(sub\/anotherSub\/|\?some_id=)\d+(-\S+)?/g
```

However, as you know, if I stick the above into a replace, it'll replace the entire string, numbers and all. How do I make it replace everything except the numbers?

**Edit:**
The issue is, I will have some links that don't follow the above format. Some links may be:

```
var dURL8='http://www.google.com/';
```

I'm looping through all links found on my webpage and adding all numbers which fit the above to an array to be acted on later. :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var result = yourstr.replace(/^.*?(?:(?:\bsub\/anotherSub\/|\?some_id=)(\d+))?[^\d\/]*$/, '$1');
```

pattern details:

```
^                         # anchor for the start of the string
.*?                       # all characters until the capturing group (lazy quantifier)
(?:                       # an optional non capturing group
    (?:                   # a non capturing group with the 2 possibilities
        \bsub\/anotherSub\/
      |                   # OR
        \?some_id=
    )                     # close the second non capturing group
    (\d+)                 # capturing group 1 with digits:
)?                        # close the first non capturing group and make it optional
[^\d\/]*                  # all that is not a digit or a slash
$
```

Note that the optional non capturing group is important if you want to obtain an empty string with `http://domain.com`

Comment: @user3389410: I have udapted my answer too.

Comment: Thank you, but the above would still replace if `var dURL9='hello/world/12345';`. It has to be specifically `sub/anotherSub/` followed by a number and possibly text afterward, or `?some_id=` followed by a number. :(.

Comment: I see your edit now! Thank you - it works great! Now to make my mind explode trying to understand it (only thing I struggle with is RegExp...).

Comment: @user3389410: I added some explanations and a little change to the pattern.

Comment: I had to edit it a bit (very slightly). Because in instances like `sub/anotherSub/12345-some-random-text-678` it was adding the 678 (or at least I think it was - I didn't check). I simply changed it to `/^.*?(?:\bsub\/anotherSub\/|\??some_id=)(\d*)(?:-\S+)*$/` and it worked great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do:

```
var num = dURL1.match(/\d+/)[0]; // 12345
```

which should work with all of your examples since you don't have numbers anywhere.

In case numbers can there in domain names then you can use:

You can use:

```
var tot = 0;
if (/sub\/anotherSub\/\d/.test(url)) {
    var num = url.match(/[=\/](\d+)/)[1];
    tot += num;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the other comment, I've updated my question. Thanks again! :).

Comment: Thanks again, anubhava, but as I mentioned to Casimir, those specific directories or be specifically some_id. :(.

Comment: But very 1st example is not `sub/anotherSub/`

Comment: I have added `sub/anotherSub/` in my regex test though

Comment: The way the website is designed, both `http://www.domain.com/?some_id=12345` and `http://www.domain.com/sub/anotherSub/12345` will take you to the same page - which is why I need to be able to detect both. :P.

The above looks great for the `sub/anotherSub/` though!

Comment: But then how to distinguish between `http://www.domain.com/?some_id=12345` and `http://www.domain.com/?foo=100` ?